# Where to read about id attribute format?

Tags: android, resources, android-xml

What does this mean

`@[+][package:]type:name`

or this

`@+id/my_id`

?

What plus does? No detailed explanation in apidoc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@[+][package:]type:name
```

You can use the id of an element from other packages. That's how themes and other variable content works. They take resource from other packages.

The plus symbol, +, indicates that this is a new resource ID and the aapt tool will create a new resource integer in the R.java class, if it doesn't already exist.

Refer:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html#idvalue

Answer (score 1):

`@+id/my_id` does mean u create a new ID for that layout object in xml.
This id is used to mount it in your JavaCode using `findViewById()` or similar.

For more infos:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html